# DocumentRoot error when starting server using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

As part of a project I have to develop a site via Symfony.
As I do not master this framework I followed a few classes on line.
Everything was going well, I could load the pages in firefox without any problem so I decided to start, so I created my bundle for the project that I have to develop and since then I can not start my server anymore.

When I make the command: php bin/console server:start
I get an error: [ERROR] The root directory document "/var/www/web" does not exist.

If I try to load the developed pages that worked previously but i getan  address not found error, indeed the server does not start.

I moved the Symfony web folder to the /var/www directory, the error does not appear anymore when starting the servor and I can "load" the pages in Firefox except that I have a blank page, the HTML is not displayed .

On the Internet I saw that this error could happen when SELinux is active but it is not on my computer. I use Ubuntu.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please show your project directory structure.

Comment: Which version of Symfony? Where is your project located (absolute path)? You mention that you moved the Symfony "web" folder. If you moved that folder - and only that folder - that's your problem. The "web" folder absolutely needs to be in your code base directory.

Comment: THis is the 3.3.2 version.

The project path is /var/www/Symfony/ then in the src folder I have two differents folders, one for the class I did to learn Symfony, and one for my project.

When I say I moved the web folder it was only to see if it'd worked. I just copy/paste I didn't cut it. So it showed that the command needed a web directory there. But since i followed exactly the same way to order directories as in the course why would it stop working and ask for a web folder that wasn't there before ?

Answer (score 0):

THis is the 3.3.2 version.

The project path is /var/www/Symfony/ then in the src folder I have two differents folders, one for the class I did to learn Symfony, and one for my project.

When I say I moved the web folder it was only to see if it'd worked. I just copy/paste I didn't cut it. So it showed that the command needed a web directory there. But since i followed exactly the same way to order directories as in the course why would it stop working and ask for a web folder that wasn't there before  ?